# How to change output of example data to 2 columns instead of 1

Tags: php

I'm using this API to pull a list of data to place on a wordpress website. Right now it outputs all 24 list items in one big div. I want to make it put the first 12 items in one column and the second 12 items in a second column. Any ideas how this can be done?

Thanks

```
   <?php                                                                    
$string = 
    $string = 
    file_get_contents("***API KEY GOES HERE***");

    $json_taps = json_decode($string, true);  


$t=1; 
echo '<div id="datafieldcontainer">'; 

foreach ($json_taps as $beverage) { 

        $item_name = $beverage['MenuItemDisplayDetail']['DisplayName'];
        $producer_name = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['FullProducerList'];
        $beverage_name = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['BeverageNameWithVintage'];
        $beverage_style = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['FullStyleName'];
        $beverage_color = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['StyleColor'];
        $year = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Year'];
        $beverage_abv = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Abv'];
        $beverage_type = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['BeverageType'];
        $producer_location = "";
        $producer_url = "";
        switch($beverage_type) {
            case "Beer":
                $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Brewery']['Location'];
                $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Brewery']['BreweryUrl'];
                break;
            case "Cider":
                $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Cidery']['Location'];
                $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Cidery']['CideryUrl'];
                break;
            case "Mead":
                $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Meadery']['Location'];
                $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Meadery']['MeaderyUrl'];
                break;
            case "Wine":
                $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Winery']['Location'];
                $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['Winery']['WineryUrl'];
                break;
            case "Kombucha":
                $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['KombuchaMaker']['Location'];
                $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['KombuchaMaker']['Url'];
                break;
            case "Soft Drink":
                $producer_location = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['SoftDrinkMaker']['Location'];
                $producer_url = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Beverage']['SoftDrinkMaker']['Url'];
                break;
        }
        $date_put_on = $beverage['DatePutOn']; 
        $bottle_size = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Prices'][0]['Size'];   
        $bottle_price = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Prices'][0]['Price'];
        $beverage_ps = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['Prices'][0]['DisplayName']; 
        $in_bottles = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['AvailableInBottles'];
        $keg_size = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['KegSize'];
        $oz_remaining = $beverage['MenuItemProductDetail']['EstimatedOzLeft'];
        $scale = 1.0; //


    //calculating percentage of keg remaining
    // Get Percentage out of 100
    if ( !empty($keg_size) ) { $percent = $oz_remaining  / $keg_size; } 
    else { $percent = 0; }

    // Limit to 100 percent (if more than the max is allowed)
    if ( $percent > 1 ) { $percent = 1; }     
    if ( $percent < 0 ) { $percent = .005; }     
    $percent_remaining = number_format($percent*100, 0);
    if ( $percent_remaining < 1 ) {$percent_remaining = "< 1";}

    //determine percent Left color
    //                  |-----------Red ---------------------------|   |-------Green--------------------| |Blue|
    $percent_left_color = (max(0,min(255,511 * (1-$percent))) * 65536) + (max(0,min(255,511 * $percent)) * 256) + 40;


    $html =  
        '<div id="responsecontainer">'.
        '<div id="boxfielddata" title="'.$percent_remaining.'% remaining" ><b>'. 

        '<span title="Tap: '.$item_name.'">'.
        $item_name.": ".
        (!empty($producer_url) ? '<a href="http://'.$producer_url.'"  
target="_blank">' : '</a>').$producer_name.'</a>'.
        '<i>'. $beverage_name.'</i></b></span>'.
        '<span style="padding:1px;margin-left:10px;border:solid black 
0px;font-size:8pt;"><a 
href="http://www.ratebeer.com/advbeersearch.php?BeerName='.$producer_name.' 
'.$beverage_name.'" target=_blank title="Click to find a Rate Beer description of 
this beverage!">RB</a><b>|</b>'.
        '<a href="http://beeradvocate.com/search?q='.$brewery_name.' 
'.$beverage_name.'&qt=beer" target=_blank title="Click to find a Beer Advocate 
description of this beverage!">BA</a></span><br>'. 
        $beverage_style.' '.(!empty ($beverage_abv) ? 
number_format($beverage_abv, 1, '.', '').'% ' : '').
        '<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q='.$beverage_location.'" 
target="_blank">'.$beverage_location.'</a> '.
        '<span>'.($beverage_ps == '12oz' ? $beverage_ps : '').'</span>'.
        '<div>'.        '<span style="position:relative;">'.($in_bottles == TRUE 
? '<a href="/dev/?page_id=7&so=brewery"><i>Available in bottles!</i></a>' : 
'').'</span>'.    
//PERCENTAGE AND COLOR
        '<div class="percentbar" style="width:'.round(100 * $scale).'px;">'.
        '<div style="width:'.round(max($percent*100,5) * $scale).'px;font-size:8pt;color:'.dechex($percent_left_color).';"></div>'.
        '</div>'.
        '</div>'.
        '</div></div>'.  

        ($t == $countnumrows ? '</div><div id="shim"></div><div 
id="datafieldcontainer">' : '');    

echo $html;
$t++;     
}
echo '</div><p>'.

'</div>';

?>
```

[This is what current output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbUF9.png)

Comment: Did you try to use a table?

Comment: I have not. I will look into that though, thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON, other than that you receive data in that format at some point. However, the result of decoding it is not JSON. So, in order to improve your question, just replace that part with example content you would get from decoding the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I removed the 'JSON' tag and the mention in the title. My apologies as I am very new to this. I want to make it right, is there anything else I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slap something like this to break up the loop. Bit crappy if you ever want to use your keys for something other than indexes though. Could use a normal for loop. Or split the array.

```
<?php
   foreach ($json_taps as $key => $beverage) { 
     ...
     if($key == 12){
        echo "</div>"
        echo "<div>"
     }
     ...
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have much experience working with php, where would I put the code relative to that function?

Comment: No problem.
You'll need to replace the foreach you have with the little edit I've made there. `$key => $beverage` will have the iteration number as `$key` (it would contain the keys in your array if you're using the keys in the associative array. like `'name' => 'Guinness'`)

Then just put the `if` statement anywhere in your loop really, the very start would work. 

A table is probably a better idea as the other commenter said.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you are using the keys sorry.
You'll need to add an index outside the loop, so put a `$i = 0;` before the foreach loop. 
And change `if($key == 12){` to `if($i == 12){`
Finally add $i++ at the end of your loop.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for your time. I'll try that out and then likely start getting a table going. Will be easier to style that way too I'd imagine.